# How to appear a field based on the two different field values?

Tags: rendered, actionsupport, actionregion

I have **3 fields** on **visualforce page** of custom object,

```
 1) gender__c:Male/female(picklist field)
 2) age__c: (number field)
 3) field3__c:(picklist field)
```

**The field3__c only display, If the gender__c=female & age__c>12.**

**code:**

**Visual force page:**

```
<apex:actionRegion>
    <apex:inputField value="{!obj.Age__c}"/>

    <apex:inputField value="{!obj.Gender__c }">
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="Pbs" />
    </apex:inputField>
</apex:actionRegion>

<apex:pageBlockSection id="pbs" rendered="true">   
    <apex:inputField id="field3" value="{!obeject.field3__c}" rendered="{IF(object__c.Gender__c="Female" & object__c.Age__c >12 ,true,false)}"/>    
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

**error:**

> Element type "apex:inputField" must be followed by either attribute
>   specifications, ">" or "/>".

Comment: are you aware of `rendered` and `rerender` attributes?

Comment: can you please post Vf code related to the fields

Comment: I have an idea on rendered and rerender, But here we are displaying the field3__c based on the 2 different field values.

Comment: @Sarath Garimella, I edited question with vf code. Hope expecting answer. Thank you.

Comment: @RavindarAdmin whatever code you posted is not helpful.  visual force page section is blank and apex class section is also not useful

Comment: @sarath Garimella, please check now.